# selenium scraping returns empty string after first few elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I am scraping a website using selenium in python. The xpath is able to find the 20 elements, which contain the search results. However, the content is available only for the first 6 elements, and the rest has empty strings. This is true for all the pages of the results

The xpath used:

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view')]")
```

xpath finds 20 elements in chrome

[image]

Text inside the results

```
[tt.text for tt in results]
```

anonymized output:

```
['Abcddwedwada',
 'Asefdasdfaca',
 'Asdaafcascac',
 'Asdadaacjkhi',
 'Sfskjfbsfvbkd',
 'Fjsbfksjnsvas',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '']
```

I have tried extracting the id of the 20 elements and used `driver.find_element_by_id`, but still I get empty strings after the first 6 elements.

Comment: could you share link to page?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Python&origin=SUGGESTION&suggestedEntities=SKILL

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
[str(tt.text) for tt in results if str(tt.text) !='']
```

OR

```
 [tt.text for tt in results if len(tt.text) > 0]
```

Comment: This filters out the results with empty strings

Comment: @mrbot what is the type of  empty string ' ' ? unicode or string?

Comment: type of the empty string is `str`

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that the reason of such result is following: when you opens the page there are 20 entries (`<li>` elements in `<ul>`), but only content of 6 displayed. Content of other elements could be displayed after scrolling down - content of those 14 entries generated dynamically from `XHR` requests.

So you might need to perform scrolling down to the last element in list:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait 

wait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view') and not(text()='')]")) == 20)
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view')]")
results[-1].location_once_scrolled_into_view
[tt.text for tt in results]
```

Try and let me know results

Comment: It didn't work. I thought of that and tried: `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y);")`

Comment: Does anything have to do with using `pyvirtualdisplay`?

Comment: all the 20 elements return `True` for `is_displayed()`

Comment: Try code from updated answer and let me know if it still doesn't work as expected

Comment: the new `wait` statement returned `True`, and the results still have empty strings after 6th result